# What's the best way to clean and maintain a Burton Channel System snowboard?

Tags: maintenance, snowboarding

I have been throwing around the idea of purchasing a [Burton Channel System](https://www.burton.com/blogs/the-burton-blog/story-behind-burtons-one-kind-snowboard-mounting-system-channel/) snowboard and everything sounds good except for the lack of information on maintenance. I have been unable to find much online about potential risks or even basic care associated with the system.

How do you deal with the snow/ice that will inevitably accumulate during the day? Will water melt and work its way into the base, causing "bubbles" if it freezes?

Comment: I have not used one but I have never has ski bindings freeze up.   It would re rare to have  a melt then a freeze during a ski day but the open channel should allow the ice to expand without damaging the board.

Comment: From watching a friend's board: yes snow gets in, but the amounts are too small too cause damage when freezing. At night just let it melt and drip out and if you want clean the remaining drops of water with a dry towel.

Comment: Oh and if you want a definitive answer I'd try here: http://www.snowboardingforum.com/forum.php

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2012 Custom that has given me no problems.  I think normal maintenance is all it takes.  Be sure to put it away dry and clean. Store properly in the off season and you should have no problems. I received [this](https://www.burton.com/us/en/p/burton-est-tool/W18-108201.html) as a gift and every now and then I will clean out the "channel" with a pipe cleaner or q-tip.